# calling a web service using WCF over Http and Https

Tags: asp.net, wcf, http, https

In our project we have a java web service that runs over http and https. 
We want to use http internally and https for the external version of our web app.

So we've created the proxy class in our application and we have setup the binding for http in the web/app.config and all works fine.

What changes would we need to make to the code and the configuration to support https for the same service in our external application? If possible please supply code snippets to explain!

Answer (score 22):

I found an answer digging around MSDN.

In my case, I was using a custom binding:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="jsonpBinding">
        <jsonpMessageEncoding/>
        <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

That was referenced in the service

```
<services>
    <service name="{YourInfoHere}">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="{YourInfoHere}" contract="{YourInfoHere}"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Adding a second binding that used httpsTransport and then a second service that used that binding did the trick. Final output:

```
    <services>
        <service name="{YourInfoHere}">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="{YourInfoHere}" contract="{YourInfoHere}"/>
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBindingHttps" behaviorConfiguration="{YourInfoHere}" contract="{YourInfoHere}"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="jsonpBinding">
                <jsonpMessageEncoding/>
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="jsonpBindingHttps">
                <jsonpMessageEncoding/>
                <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

May not be ideal, but it works. These were the only changes I made to make SSL work. Since it is all in the binding & transport, the code remains the same.

Relevant MSDN links:

1. Custom Binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731377.aspx
2. HttpTransport: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.aspx
3. HttpsTransport: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httpstransportbindingelement.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are using basichttpbinding. Then you need to do two things:

- change the address to https :)
- set the security mode to transport

Comment: nice - linking to the same question :)

Comment: @Rory, nice catch, answer has been there over a year, you are the first to notice :)

Comment: As obvious as your answer is, it just saved me potentially hours. `I am assuming that you are using basichttpbinding.` My SLL was working for SOAP, but it doesnt not work for webHttpBinding -REST. Now that I identified the problem, I can begin to fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx):

> Using Windows Communication Foundation
>   (WCF) over HTTP either requires the
>   use of a host, such as Internet
>   Information Services (IIS), or manual
>   configuration of the HTTP settings
>   through the HTTP Server API. This
>   document describes manually
>   configuring WCF when using HTTP and
>   HTTPS.

And also see [WCF Bindings Needed For HTTPS](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx):

> I just finished writing my first
>   production WCF application, which
>   worked very well until I deployed it
>   to our production environment.  All of
>   a sudden none of the WCF calls would
>   work, and I would get a JavaScript
>   "TestService is not defined" error. 
>   When I look inside the JS service
>   reference (in debug mode), I got the
>   following error:
>
> *Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint
>   with binding WebHttpBinding.
>   Registered base address schemes are
>   [https]*
>
> So apparently my WCF service
>   registered itself as HTTPS (since it
>   is over SSL), but my binding was only
>   configured for HTTP.  The solution is
>   to define a custom binding inside your
>   Web.Config file and set the security
>   mode to "Transport".  Then you just
>   need to use the bindingConfiguration
>   property inside your endpoint
>   definition to point to your custom
>   binding.  The entire HTTPS-enabled
>   system.serviceModel section is below:

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using WCF to build the client, that connects to a remote web service, over HTTPS.

To do this, just modify the client-side config file for the WCF-powered app, replacing http://server.address with https://server.address, in configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint/@address .  like so:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    ...
    <client>
        <!-- change only the address string -->
        <endpoint address="https://server.name/Whatever"
            everything.else.stays.the.same />

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

(The path to the config file varies according to the regular .NET rules: whether it is an ASPNET app, or a service, or etc.)

OR you can set the address explicitly in code:

```
    // instantiate new proxy to web service
    var svc= new ServiceClient();
    var e = svc.Endpoint;
    e.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://server.address/JavaServiceUri");
```

I strongly advise you to make the address configurable, and not hard-code it.  That does not mean it must be stored in app.config, but it should be changeable. The proxy, too.

Comment: This doesn't work for my situation, it results in a System.ArgumentException with message "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'."