# Getting 404 no endpoint listening error WCF 4.0 using Https basicHttpBinding over Transport security

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-binding

I am trying to get https security working for my wcf web service hosted in IIS 7.5. I have looked through every article I can find online regarding this and tried just about every configuration or IIS trick I could find or variation. I think this might be a IIS, windows level configuration issue. We are using a wild card SSL cert like *.mycompany.com. This cert is being used on 3 other sites already in same IIS if that has any bearing. Does anyone have any idea what I am running into here??? This is a public server, non TEST and http binding works fine. I am having this same https issue on my dev and production servers. We have another https website on this production box and it sends and receives data just fine. I am getting Exception :

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://subdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>
> Inner Exception :
>
> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Here is my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings file="LocalAppSettings.config">
      <!--<add key="CustomIISServiceHostEndPoint" value="https://subdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc" />-->
   </appSettings>
   <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="COLWebServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="134217727" sendTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00">
        <security mode="Transport">
           <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="65536" maxBytesPerRead="65536" maxStringContentLength="134217727" />
     </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="COLWebService.ServiceBehavior" name="COLWebService">
    <endpoint address="https://subdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="MyCompany.COLWebService.ICOLWebService"
              bindingConfiguration="COLWebServiceBinding" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="errorHandler" type="MyCompany.COLWebService.ErrorHandlerBehaviorExtensionElement, MyCompany.COLWebService" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="COLWebService.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <!--<behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>-->
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer> 
 </configuration>
```

And here is my client's `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                 <binding name="wsHttpBinding_ICOLWebService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="134217727"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="134217727" maxArrayLength="65536"
                    maxBytesPerRead="65536" />
                      <security mode="Transport">
                          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                     </security>
                 </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
         </bindings>
        <client>
             <endpoint address="https://subdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_ICOLWebService"
            contract="COLWebService.ICOLWebService" name="wsHttpBinding_ICOLWebServiceEP" />
          </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried just opening a browser and navigating to the svc address? I often find that much more informative than trying to work through the WCF errors.

Comment: Yes if I only have the https binding it seems to navigate ok but MEX is turned off even though I have turned on for MEXHttps in config file. But it should work with or without mex being on.

Comment: I thought it might be because I used the UI to assign the wildcard certificate to each site instead of using the command line. Nope, I went and deleted all the https bindings from all my sites and then binded them all to https using same wild card certificate using command line like this site told me to. http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html. Just like this appcmd set site /site.name:"<IISSiteName>" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:<hostHeaderValue>']

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add host header values to SSL certificates by modifying the applicationhost.config file in system32\inetsrv. Look for the  section for your IIS instance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the https binding has not been configured for the new site.

In IIS, select the site, then click on advanced settings and check the contents of Bindings. Make sure that https is in the list.

**Edit**

The other thing that it could be is that the svc handler is not activated. Is ASP.Net turned on for the site?

You should test it without the https first, to make sure that the problem is related to https.

**Edit 2**

Make sure that the site is started. Have you checked that you can access the svc via a browser.

You have several sites on the machine, all use https. Have you configured host headers to allow all sites to use https? Is https on this site on a different port?

Comment: It is started. Yes I have. It shows in  browser but it says Mex is turned off because I only have https mex binding on and not http. But I only want https. Yes all the sites are using https on this IIS server with same *.mycompany.com wildcard certificate. They are all using port 443 for their https port.

Answer (score 0):

Open the .svc file - I would guess its not referencing COLWebService as the service.

Your config file has:

```
name="COLWebService"
```

in the service declaration. This needs to match .SVC's named service, which looking at the url you've given, I think will be 'MyService'.

Comment: I just changed the names of things for posting online purposes. It does match like you said I think, I will double check though.

Answer (score 0):

Your service model section should be like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="/ssl"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="COLWebService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint address="/ssl" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="MyCompany.COLWebService.ICOLWebService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And your clients will access servis over https https://subdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc/ssl, over http same as old https://subdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc

Comment: Why do I need a /ssl for https? Why can't they both use same address and just change the first part of the url to http or https??? It should just auto handle that in IIS and map it for me.

Comment: endpoints addresses should be unique, so http and https addresses must be different http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733107.aspx. this is the way it works for me, there is another post you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1989478/1175585

Comment: Hmmm. Did you ever try just using basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding using Tranport security mode instead of this custom binding with HttpTransport node element? Also I only want this service to be available through https, not http at all.